# simulate by integration $x e^{-x} \sin(x)\mathrm dx$ with Monte Carlo

Tags: probability, statistics

does anyone know how to simulate by integration $x e^{-x} \sin(x)\mathrm dx$ by using Monte Carlo method ($\frac 1 n \sum Y$)?

Comment: More details please. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you integration limits are $0$ and $\infty$ you can use $X\simGamma(2,1)$ random variables and compute $1/n \sum sin(X_i)$

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible with a bit of Python. I have assumed that you only wish to sample between x=0 to x=pi. We simply generate points random uniformally over a rectangle, and keep the points under the curve

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x*np.e**(-x)*np.sin(x)

n = 1000
xs = np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, n)
ys = np.random.uniform(0, 0.4, n)
plt.scatter(xs, ys, s=5)


x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

This yields:
[image]

```
final = [i for i in range(len(xs)) if ys[i] <= f(xs[i])]

plt.scatter(xs[final], ys[final], s=5)

plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

This yields your final sample which you can access with xs[final]

[image]

The area under the curve is approximated as the proportion of points under the curve out of all points multiplied by the size of the rectangle:

```
len(final)/len(xs) * np.pi*0.4
```

With only n=1000, this gives me 0.6258. n=1,000,000 gave 0.5895.

Let me know if there is a mistake in my methodology, it's been a while!

Comment: Thanks for your help! is it the same if I use Console R ?